# Resize sprited image

Tags: html, css, resize, css-sprites

I would like to resize a sprited background-image. My sprite-picture returns after the spriting (?) a 8px*8px picture. I would like to resize it to 80px*80px. I am not able to resize the whole picture because it is on an extern server.

My code:

```
.mc-skin{
  background: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/TupidaMC.png') -8px -8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

Is there any way to resize the background image? I hope I explained my problem good enough...

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/WL7HK/1/

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to make the .big-skin as big as the .mc-skin"? The width / height? That would be `width` and `height` then.

Comment: Yes I mean this. But if I change the width and height to 80px it looks like the bottom image at the jsfiddle.

Comment: Then I don't understand what is wrong with the bottom image...?

Comment: You can see it in the jsfiddle. It isn't sprited and distorted.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand - you want to show a single *square* of the whole sprite-image? Then you can't resize it to 80x80, of course! You have to keep proportions.

Comment: So there isn't any way to solve my problem?

Comment: There is, kind of, but the browser will always render it blurry. Check the link in my updated answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes this is it! I can prevent the blurring with: image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;

Comment: Well then. I updated the answer to reflect the changes. :) Feel free to accept it if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `background-size: 640px 320px` for that, and it already has decent [browser support.](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Example:

```
.mc-skin{
  background: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/TupidaMC.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 640px 320px;
  background-position: -80px -80px; /* adjusted for increased size */
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;  
  display: block;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;         /* Firefox */
  image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;         /* Opera */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;/* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;  /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WL7HK/4/

Comment: Yes this works. But: If I set the width and height of the whole div the sprite won't be applicated...

Comment: Can you provide an example of that? Or even better, a live demo http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Oh I see... I forgot the jsfiddle ^^